# Timezone - Make non-UTC datetime timezone aware

Tags: python, django, timezone

I have a case where I get an `CET` datetime (via my API) and I want to save it in my `django` database.

When I do this I always get a runtime warning:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(last_content_update)
```

When I add the `replace` part I don't get the error but my date is not correct (1h shift):

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(last_content_update).replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

Any idea how I can load my datetime timezone aware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally I found out that the `fromtimestamp()` takes an timezone parameter!

Just do it like this:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(last_content_update, tz=pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris"))
```

[Here is a link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in two steps:

1. First, make the datetime timezone-aware - in your case, using the CET (Central European Time) timezone.
2. Second, convert the datetime to UTC before saving it.  This is because [Django stores datetimes as UTC](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#overview):

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime
>   information in UTC in the database...

This can be done like this:

```
import pytz    
from django.utils import timezone

# Convert the naive datetime into a CET datetime
local_datetime = timezone.make_aware(naive_datetime, pytz.timezone('CET'))

# Convert the CET datetime to UTC
utc_datetime = local_datetime.astimezone(timezone.utc)

# Now it can be saved in the database on a model field
MyDateModel.objects.create(title='Another date model',
                           created=utc_datetime)
```

Comment: My original answer was downvoted as I didn't take into account converting it from Central European Time; I've corrected it now.